# Sanitize HTML as XHTML to draw DOM object to SVG to Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, html5-canvas, xhtml

I am following this guide - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas - to draw element to canvas.

I however am taking the innerHTML of a div on my page. When I do this I have things like `<br>` and `<img>` and `&nbsp;`. And this is causing it to error. If I replace br and img with regex to self closing tags and remove all the `&nbsp;` it works, however it doesnt look like it is supposed to. The user expected it the spaces to be there.

Is there any sanitizer/parser to properly parse my string as XHTML?

I researched here - `DOMParser` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

However that is not working.

In the below snippet, I have given this. If you load it then click "Make img" you will get prompted with a data url, paste that to a new tab and you can see it works fine. However in the content editable div, hit enter a few times, and then try "Make Image" and it will fail.

```js
function makeimg() {

  var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var txt = document.getElementById('rawr').innerHTML;

  var w = 200;
  var h = 200;

  canvas.width = w;
  canvas.height = h;

  var data = '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="' + w + '" height="' + h + '"><foreignObject width="100%" height="100%">' + txt + '</foreignObject></svg>';

  var img = new Image();
  var svg = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
  });
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(svg);

  img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    prompt('', canvas.toDataURL('image/png', ''));
  }

  img.src = url;

}
```

```html
<div id="rawr" contenteditable="true">
  rawr rawr !!! hi! yep y
</div>
<button onClick="makeimg()">Make img</button>
```

Comment: Maybe something like XMLSerializer().serializeToString(). But don't follow this guide, it's totally misleading and should make it clear that it is a hack not supported by IE nor safari and only partially in FF and chrome. The only real way to draw html on canvas is through the canvas drawing method, just like html2canvas does.

Comment: Absolutely superb!!! Thank you @Kaiido! If you can please move that to solution I would love to accept!

Comment: Actually re-reading your article, the XMLSerializer() is [already in it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas#DrawingHTML)

Comment: Oh shoots I missed that haha. Thanks for pointing that out. I would love to accept your solution though please